# LINQ - database query using "into", how do I reference data prior to "into" in the select clause?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-objects

firstly apologies for the title of this question - I don't know how better to express it.

The query below retrieves the total sales of a product for Jan, Feb, Mar of 2014, as well as the Total of those 3 months, and the Average monthly sales.
However I also want to retrieve data from the table StockItems (joined below with alias s) column header FreeStockQuantity, and including that in the returned data.
I had hoped to simply add a line into the select clause similar to:
Stock = s.FreeStockQuantity
however this returns error:
Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type
The name 's' does not exist in the current context

What is the correct syntax to reference a table which precedes the "group d by s.ItemID into g"?

Many thanks in advance for any help. I'm new at this!

```
var Sales= from d in cxt.SOPDespatchReceiptLines 

join l in cxt.SOPOrderReturnLines on d.SOPOrderReturnLineID equals l.SOPOrderReturnLineID
join o in cxt.SOPOrderReturns on l.SOPOrderReturnID equals o.SOPOrderReturnID
join s in cxt.StockItems on l.ItemCode equals s.Code
join p in cxt.ProductGroups on s.ProductGroupID equals p.ProductGroupID
join c in cxt.SLCustomerAccounts on o.CustomerID equals c.SLCustomerAccountID
where d.DespatchReceiptDate.Year ==2014
orderby d.SOPOrderReturnLine.ItemCode
//group d by d.SOPOrderReturnLine.ItemCode into g

group d by s.ItemID into g


select new
{

ItemID = g.Key,
Total = g.Sum(d=>d.DespatchReceiptQuantity),
Average = (g.Sum(d=>d.DespatchReceiptQuantity))/3,
Jan = g.Sum(d => d.DespatchReceiptDate.Month==01 ? d.DespatchReceiptQuantity : 0),
Feb= g.Sum(d => d.DespatchReceiptDate.Month==02 ? d.DespatchReceiptQuantity : 0),
Mar= g.Sum(d => d.DespatchReceiptDate.Month==03 ? d.DespatchReceiptQuantity : 0),

};

return Sales;
```

Comment: you need simple add `s` to group value like `group new {d, s} by s.ItemID into g`, or add it in key like  `group d by new {s.ItemID, s.FreeStockQuantity} into g`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried to use `group new {d, s} by s.ItemID into g` which gave me the error: `Cannot convert lambda expression to type string because it is not a delegate type
AnonymousType#1 does not contain a definition for DespatchReceiptQuantity and no extension method DespatchReceiptQuantity accepting a first argument of type AnonymousType#1 could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: When I tried the 2nd suggestion `group d by new {s.ItemID, s.FreeStockQuantity} into g` the query ran without an error, however when I then inserted the line `Stock = s.FreeStockQuantity` it gave me the same kind of error I was getting before: `Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type
The name 's' does not exist in the current context`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Methinks you not quite understood what i mean in comment. So try add more explained sample

first variant `group new {d, s}`

```
var Sales= from d in cxt.SOPDespatchReceiptLines 

join l in cxt.SOPOrderReturnLines on d.SOPOrderReturnLineID equals l.SOPOrderReturnLineID
join o in cxt.SOPOrderReturns on l.SOPOrderReturnID equals o.SOPOrderReturnID
join s in cxt.StockItems on l.ItemCode equals s.Code
join p in cxt.ProductGroups on s.ProductGroupID equals p.ProductGroupID
join c in cxt.SLCustomerAccounts on o.CustomerID equals c.SLCustomerAccountID
where d.DespatchReceiptDate.Year ==2014
orderby d.SOPOrderReturnLine.ItemCode
//group d by d.SOPOrderReturnLine.ItemCode into g

group new {d,s} by s.ItemID into g

select new
{
    ItemID = g.Key,
    Total = g.Sum(d=>d.d.DespatchReceiptQuantity),
    Average = (g.Sum(d=>d.d.DespatchReceiptQuantity))/3,
    Jan = g.Sum(d => d.d.DespatchReceiptDate.Month==01 ? d.d.DespatchReceiptQuantity : 0),
    Feb= g.Sum(d => d.d.DespatchReceiptDate.Month==02 ? d.d.DespatchReceiptQuantity : 0),
    Mar= g.Sum(d => d.d.DespatchReceiptDate.Month==03 ? d.d.DespatchReceiptQuantity : 0),
    Stock = g.First(s=>s.s)
};

return Sales;
```

second way `by new {s.ItemID, s.FreeStockQuantity}`

```
var Sales= from d in cxt.SOPDespatchReceiptLines 

join l in cxt.SOPOrderReturnLines on d.SOPOrderReturnLineID equals l.SOPOrderReturnLineID
join o in cxt.SOPOrderReturns on l.SOPOrderReturnID equals o.SOPOrderReturnID
join s in cxt.StockItems on l.ItemCode equals s.Code
join p in cxt.ProductGroups on s.ProductGroupID equals p.ProductGroupID
join c in cxt.SLCustomerAccounts on o.CustomerID equals c.SLCustomerAccountID
where d.DespatchReceiptDate.Year ==2014
orderby d.SOPOrderReturnLine.ItemCode
//group d by d.SOPOrderReturnLine.ItemCode into g

group d by new {s.ItemID, s.FreeStockQuantity} into g

select new
{
    ItemID = g.Key.ItemID,
    Total = g.Sum(d=>d.d.DespatchReceiptQuantity),
    Average = (g.Sum(d=>d.d.DespatchReceiptQuantity))/3,
    Jan = g.Sum(d => d.d.DespatchReceiptDate.Month==01 ? d.d.DespatchReceiptQuantity : 0),
    Feb= g.Sum(d => d.d.DespatchReceiptDate.Month==02 ? d.d.DespatchReceiptQuantity : 0),
    Mar= g.Sum(d => d.d.DespatchReceiptDate.Month==03 ? d.d.DespatchReceiptQuantity : 0),
    Stock = k.Key.FreeStockQuantity
};

return Sales;
```

Comment: Thank you **very** much for your assistance. I couldn't get the first way to work (I was still getting an error Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type) however the second way works perfectly.